# IE7 issue with a div on top of another div so it will look disabled

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have placed a div `.ontopdivs` on top of another div `.notradewin` with jQuery so it will look like it is disabled, it works fine with all browsers except IE7.

In IE7 everything in the lower div is still working: image hover, select open on click, text that i can mark.

(It is not a form and to use `disabled="disabled"` is not the answer. tried it)

The select is a plugin that I wrote so I guess I can fix this in the plugin but all of the links are still working.

jQuery code:

```
$("div.notradewin").each(function() {
    var thisoffset = $(this).offset();
    var thiswidth = $(this).width() + 4;
    var thisheight = $(this).height() + 4;
    $("#bodywrap").append('<div class="ontopdivs" style="background-color: transparent; width: ' + thiswidth + 'px; height:' + thisheight + 'px;position: absolute;top:' + thisoffset.top + 'px;left: ' + thisoffset.left + 'px;z-index: 12 !important;overflow: hidden;"></div>')
})
```

How do I get this to work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use Block UI, it has ability to block specific elements. 
http://jquery.malsup.com/block/#element

Comment: i didn't know Block UI can do this for specific elements. thanks

Answer (score 1):

There is a known issue with mouse events on transparent backgrounds in IE. See [this post](http://blog.rednael.com/2009/09/01/TrappingMouseEventsOnTransparentInputElementsOrTextareasInIE.aspx) explaining the issue.

Try adding `background-image: url(.)` if you must have transparent background.

Answer (score 0):

In IE7, fully-transparent elements do not receive click events (or hover, apparently). Try putting the following in a [stylesheet for IE7 and older](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/condcom.html) (referenced [here](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/opacity.html)):

```
filter: alpha(opacity=1);
```

This will set the opacity to 1%, which will appear transparent, but should still allow intercepting click events.

Comment: I want the top div to block all the clicks or hover that is happening in the lower div. so the lower div will be disabled.

Comment: Right, and the fact that the top div is transparent _causes_ the clicks and hovers not to be blocked in IE7.